# Access the android notifications of other applications

Tags: android

Is it possible to programatically access the text posted on the android notification area (displayed by an application which is not my own)?

The logic I am after would be something like...

```
for each (NotificationMessage m in NotificationArea.Notifications)
{
  String msg = m.GetMessage()
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, no. This would create security concerns, possibly hijacking personal information. See [This Thread](http://groups.google.com/group/android-beginners/browse_thread/thread/73cc6d5a60386be8)

Answer (score 1):

In Android 4.3 and above, use the NotificationListenerService. Otherwise use Accessibility.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService.html

Answer (score 0):

This is possible with the accessibility service, but you have to pick up on notifications as they arrive (ie there isn't a list you can iterate around at any point). You'd need to build that up yourself.